# When making website inaccessible by anonymous users, ajax client side does not work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, authorization

When I set:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

in my root web.config, these errors pop up in my page in the browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by adding this in my web.config:

```
<location path="bundles">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```